# How to select multiple values without ctrl key when select values are loaded dynamically as a function of another select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-applications, wicket

I am using the 'wicket' framework in my web application. I have two selects like this:

```
<select wicket:id="brands" onchange="applyMultiSelection ();">
 <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
</select>

<select wicket:id="models" id="models">
 <option value="A">A</option>
</select>
```

Using wicket models, the second's values are loaded dynamically after the value in the first one has been selected. The second is a multi select (is created with wicket's ListMultipleChoice).

In order to select several values without pressing the ctrl key, I have added to the html head the following:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
    .multi-selection {
        background-color: Highlight;
        color: HighlightText;
    }
</style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Applies multiselection on select tags
        var multiselection = function(){
            $("#models").MultiSelect({
                css_class_selected: "multi-selection"
            });
        };

        function applyMultiSelection () {
            $('#models').ready( multiselection() );
        }
    </script>
```

It doesn't seem to work, I have tried something similar for a multi select in static html and it allows me to select multiple values just clicking with the mouse, so I suspect I could be close to the solution. Any ideas?

Comment: use `.ready()` only with `document` like `$(document).ready(function(){...});`

Comment: @Spokey thanks for the tip, I'm a jquery greenhorn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main problem is that the values are dynamically updated, at the time your code runs `select` probably is empty. You can shorten the script a lot more by merging the functions in one.

```
$(function(){ // this is short for $(document).ready()
     function applyMultiSelection (){
         $("#models").MultiSelect({
             css_class_selected: "multi-selection"
         });
     };
});
```

If you cannot edit the script to add a trigger event or something similar I could suggest using the following plugin.

https://github.com/hazzik/livequery/blob/master/jquery.livequery.js

This plugin will check if there are new `option` elements added or created. Now every time you dynamically add new elements the plugin should run `.MultiSelect()`

```
$(function(){ 
   $("#models option").livequery(function () {
       $("#models").MultiSelect({
             css_class_selected: "multi-selection"
       });
   });
});
```

[**Here's a test fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/f5c82/1/)

Comment: "I think the main problem is that the values are dynamically updated" Yes, that is exactly the problem. I also suspect that using wicket has something to with it. It wraps javascript between CDATA. Thanks for the suggestion in any case.

Comment: @Jubbat I am guessing you cannot change wicket's script?

Comment: I may have found a solution if you don't mind using a plugin. Check update.

Comment: Thanks so much, that works beautifully. I don't know if it's overkill, but I least I got it done.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are putting your code in the head section, you should try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        // Applies multiselection on select tags
        var multiselection = (function(){
            $("#models").MultiSelect({
                css_class_selected: "multi-selection"
            })();
        };
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I changed my code to that but it doesn't seem to work. Were you suggesting that it shouldn't go in the head section?

Comment: If put js code in head section, you have to wait for DOM ready. If you put script just before closing body tag (</body>), you don't have as DOM is already 'ready'.

Answer (score 1):

try 2 use select2multichoice of select2 library.

http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

it very useful and simple integrated.

Comment: Interesting choice. The multiple select doesn't have the kind of visual style / functionality I'm looking for, but I'm glad to know this plugin exists.